# To find the difference b/w two numbers in a column of file?

Tags: python

Consider a input file with 5 column(0-5):

```
 1  0   937 306 97  3
 2  164472  75  17  81  3
 3  197154  35268   306 97  3
 4  310448  29493   64  38  1
 5  310541  29063   64  38  1
 6  310684  33707   64  38  1
 7  319091  47451   16  41  1
 8  319101  49724   16  41  1
 9  324746  61578   1   5   1
10  324939  54611   1   5   1
```

for the second column i,e column1(0,164472,197154-----------) need to find the difference b/w numbers so that the column1 should be (0,164472-0,197154-164472,***_*___**) so (0,164472,32682..............).

And the output file must change only the column1 values all other values must remain the same as input file:

```
 1  0   937 306 97  3
 2  164472  75  17  81  3
 3  32682   35268   306 97  3
 4  113294  29493   64  38  1
 5  93  29063   64  38  1
 6  143 33707   64  38  1
 7  8407    47451   16  41  1
 8  10  49724   16  41  1
 9  5645    61578   1   5   1
10  193 54611   1   5   1
```

if anyone could suggest a python code to do this it would be helpfull........

Actually i tried to append all the columns into list and find the difference of column2 and again write back to another file.But the input file i have posed is just a sample the entire input file contains 50,000 lines so my attempt failed

The attempt code i tried is as follows:

```
 import sys
 import numpy
 old_stdout = sys.stdout

 log_file = open("newc","a")

 sys.stdout = log_file
 a1 = []; a2 = []; a2f = []; v = []; a3 = []; a4 = []; a5 = []; a6 = []
 with open("newfileinput",'r') as f:
   for line in f:
     job = map(int,line.split())
     a1.append(job[0])
     a3.append(job[2])
     a4.append(job[3])
     a5.append(job[4])
     a6.append(job[5])
     a2.append(job[1])
   v = [a2[i+1]-a2[i] for i in range(len(a2)-1)]
print a1
print v
print a3
print a4
print a5
print a6


sys.stdout = old_stdout

log_file.close()
```

Now from the output file of the code "newc" which contained 6 list i wrote it in to an file one by one...Which was time consuming.... & not so efficient...

So if anyone could suggest a simpler method it will be helpful..........

Comment: Can I suggest that you have a try and post your attempt even if you think you may be some way off. Also, please cam you confirm what delimiter is used in your text files (i.e. are the columns just separated by spaces, commas etc).

Comment: @ChrisProsser the columns are separated by spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. let me know if any problems or if you want me to explain any of the code:

```
import sys
log_file = open("newc.txt","a")
this_no, prev_no = 0, 0

with open("newfileinput.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.split()
        this_no = int(row[1])
        log_file.write(line.replace(str(this_no), str(this_no - prev_no)))
        prev_no = this_no

log_file.close()
```

Comment: @jhon cooper can you help

Answer (score 0):

don't downvote me, just for fun.

```
import re
from time import sleep

p = re.compile(r'\s+')

data = '''1  0   937 306 97  3
2  164472  75  17  81  3
3  197154  35268   306 97  3
4  310448  29493   64  38  1
5  310541  29063   64  38  1
6  310684  33707   64  38  1
7  319091  47451   16  41  1
8  319101  49724   16  41  1
9  324746  61578   1   5   1
10  324939  54611   1   5   1\n''' * 5000

data = data.split('\n')[0:-1]
data = [p.split(one) for one in data]
data = [map(int, one) for one in data]


def list_diff(a, b):
    temp = a[:]
    temp[1] = a[1] - b[1]
    return temp

result = [
        data[0],
    ]

for i, _ in enumerate(data):
    if i < len(data) - 1:
        result.append(list_diff(data[i+1], data[i]))

for i, one in enumerate(result):
    one[0] = i+1
    print one
    sleep(0.1)
```